# Popup for ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer point data

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-10.2, popup, dynamic-layer

I was going through this example from ESRI Resource 
[popup](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/query_dojochart.html).
I was able to integrate it to my polygon layer but it is failing for point and line layer.I am not sure but

```
query.spatialRelationship = esri.tasks.Query.SPATIAL_REL_INTERSECTS;
```

could be the reason.I tried the other combination of the task but was not successful if anyone has another example or if anyone could suggest something in existing example then it will be very helpful.I am using ArcGIS server 10.2,Javascript API 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

check out this blog post for information on querying points/polylines 'onClick'
http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/01/15/querying-points-and-lines-on-click-with-the-arcgis-javascript-api/